# magento 1.9 order email total column move to right

Tags: magento-1.9, order-email

I am using `Magento 1.9.3`. In the order email, I am just adding product image. After adding this `total` column showing some white space. Following image will explain you clearly:

[image]

My query is how can I use `colspan` in that column..? or how can I move to right corner?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`app\design\frontend\base\default\layout\sales.xml`

```
<action method="setLabelProperties"><value>colspan="3" align="right" style="padding:3px 9px"</value></action>
```

Change to

```
<action method="setLabelProperties"><value>colspan="4" align="right" style="padding:3px 9px"</value></action>
```

**EDIT:**

According to the rules of Magento, it's forbidden to modify the Magento core files `base/default` !, to apply this solution you should update it in **local**.

Go to `app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/layout/local.xml` then put this before `</layout>` tag

```
<sales_email_order_items>
    <reference name="invoice_totals">
        <action method="setLabelProperties"><value>colspan="4" align="right" style="padding:3px 9px"</value></action>
    </reference>
</sales_email_order_items>
```

Comment: It's forbidden to modify the core files `base/default`

Comment: Is there any other way to change..? @Prince

Comment: Yes, in local.xml

Comment: Can you please upload your code @Prince

Comment: look my update please

Comment: @Prince: For me not working

Comment: I haven't tested it, but if your solution is correct, this one also work

Comment: i updated my answer